# How to get notification response data using Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM notification to send notification.
When I send a notification from the firebase console then I get the notification. But when I send the notification from the server, I get success but the notification doesn't appear..

Secondly, how do I get the notification response data?

My `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function is also not working.  Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

 print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
    print("success")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
    print("success")
}

func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
    print("success")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo) { (UIBackgroundFetchResult) in

       print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
    print("success")
    }

   print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
    print("success")

    let state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    // user tapped notification while app was in background
    if state == .inactive || state == .background {
        print("Inactive")
    }
    else {
        print("Active")
    }
}
```

Comment: How are sending the notification payload from the server ? Can you post that payload here...

Comment: when you send notification from server, are you using FCM token or device Token ?

Comment: i am using FCM token while sending notification from the server

Comment: I am using this notification payload . {
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Notification with custom payload!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "content-available" : 1
    },
     "data" :{
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
     }
}

Comment: I am having this issue using Firebase Admin Java SDK, notifications arrives to Android devices. But not for iOS devices. And also using the Firebase Console it works, and using the Legacy Api also works.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the message below works best for me both with Android and iOS (I use a firebase function to send it but that shouldn't matter). Note that for this to work you need to use the send method and not one of the deprecated ones, so something like: `admin.messaging().send(message)`

Message to feed to the `send`:

```
const message = {
    token: addresseePushToken,
    /*
       Apple Push Notification Service
       https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns
    */
    apns: {
      headers: {
        'apns-priority': 10,        // defaults to 10 (send immediately), can be set to 5 (consider device power)
        'apns-collapse-id': chatId  // group multiple notifications into a single notification (must not exceed 64 bytes)
      },
      payload: {
        aps: {
          alert: {
            title: title,
            body: doc.message,
          },
          badge: unseenCount+1,
        }
      }
    },
    /*
       Android specifics
       https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#android_specific_fields
    */
    android: {
      priority: 'high',               // either 'normal' or 'high' - high send immediately & waking sleeping device
      notification: {                 // notification object creates status bar notification if app in background
        tag: chatId,                  // key for grouping notifications (Android only)
        title: title,
        body: doc.message,
        color: '#ffffff',             // notification's icon color
        icon: thumbUrl,               // if not specified FCM displays the launcher icon as defined in app manifest
      }
    },
    // data object is available to the app both when received in foreground and background
    data: {
      type: 'chat',
      senderId: senderId,
      title: title,
      body: doc.message,
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved an issue very similar to this adding this to the Firebase notification:

```
"apns" : {
  "payload" : {
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
     }
  }
}
```